# Error when using reduce() in Swift 2.0

Tags: function, swift, reduce, swift2

**Note: This also applies for Swift 3.0**

When I attempt to use the `reduce` function, I get an error saying:

> reduce is unavailable: call the 'reduce()' method on the sequence

I already figured out how to do this with the `enumerate()` function but I cannot seem to solve this issue. Here is the line of code returning the error:

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return reduce(blocks, 0) { $0.hashValue ^ $1.hashValue }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You fix this the same way that you fixed your problem with `enumerate()`. In Swift 2, reduce has been removed as a global function and has been added as an instance method on all objects that conform to the `SequenceType` protocol via a protocol extension. Usage is as follows.

```
var hashValue: Int {
    return blocks.reduce(0) { $0.hashValue ^ $1.hashValue }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure because of the two values within reduce().